# @RefreshScope with @ConditionalOnProperty does not work

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, runtime, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

**Problem**

Exploring an option of enabling/disabling a **`@RequestMapping`** endpoint on demand without restarting JVM. Implement a kill switch on a endpoint at runtime.

**Attempt**

I've tried the following but **`@RefreshScope`** does not seem to work with **`@ConditionOnProperty`**

```
@RestController
@RefreshScope
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "stackoverflow.endpoints", havingValue = "enabled")
public class MyController {

    @Value("${stackoverflow.endpoints}")
    String value;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> process() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(value);
    }

}
```

Updated property using

```
POST /env?stackoverflow.endpoints=anyvalue
```

And reloaded context using

```
POST /refresh
```

At this point the controller returns the updated value.

**Question**

Are there any other ways to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Basically what you want to do is not possible. The link below explains why.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1645

Answer (score 1):

Conditions in Boot are only applied at the Configuration class level or at the bean definition level.

This might help you.

```
public class MyWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="stackoverflow.endpoints",name = "enabled")
 public MyController myController() {
    return new MyController ();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Spenser Gibb said [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1645#issuecomment-653070180), this behavior is not supported.