# Use Spring @RefreshScope, @Conditional annotations to replace bean injection at runtime after a ConfigurationProperties has changed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm running a PoC around replacing bean injection at runtime after a ConfigurationProperties has changed. This is based on spring boot dynamic configuration properties support as well summarised [here](https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7) by Dave Syer from Pivotal.

In my application I have a simple interface implemented by two different concrete classes:

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "'${config.dynamic.context.country}' == 'it'")
public class HelloIT implements HelloService {
    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Ciao dall'italia";
    }
  }
```

and

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "'${config.dynamic.context.country}' == 'us'")
public class HelloUS implements HelloService {
    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hi from US";
    }

}
```

application.yaml served by spring cloud config server is:

```
config:
  name: Default App
  dynamic:
    context:
      country: us
```

and the related ConfigurationProperties class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties (prefix = "config.dynamic")
public class ContextHolder {

private Map<String, String> context;
  Map<String, String> getContext() {
     return context;
}

public void setContext(Map<String, String> context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

My client app entrypoint is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class App1Application {

@Autowired
private HelloService helloService;

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    return helloService.sayHello();
}
```

First time I browse `http://locahost:8080/hello` endpoint it returns "Hi from US"

After that I change `country: us` in `country: it` in application.yaml in spring config server, and then hit the `actuator/refresh` endpoint ( on the client app).

Second time I browse `http://locahost:8080/hello` it stills returns "Hi from US" instead of "ciao dall'italia" as I would expect.

Is this use case supported in spring boot 2  when using @RefreshScope? In particular I'm referring to the fact of using it along with @Conditional annotations.

Comment: Relevant open GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1089 and SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271052/refreshscope-with-conditionalonproperty-does-not-work

Comment: `@ConditionalOn*` annotations are meant to be used in `@Configuration` classes, not on beans directly. Configuration aren't re-run at refresh scope, just the individual beans are recreated. I would inject the `@ConfigurationProperties` into a single bean to get the desired effect. `@RefreshScope` also behaves badly on `@Configuration` classes, it is meant only for individual beans.

Comment: @spencergibb I'm not sure I understood how you would get the same effect injecting the `@ConfigurationProperties`. Looking at my example, are you saying to inject it into `App1Application` bean ( which has `@RefreshScope` annotation) and then using it to select the desired HelloService implementation programatically ( using for example applicationContext.getBean() ) ?

Comment: Refresh scope can't change which bean is loaded, it can only re initialize a bean

Comment: @spencergibb ok, so it's clear that this is the wrong path for replacing spring bean implementation at runtime based on configuration changes. The purpose of this PoC was to select business logic at runtime based on context changes. I think I will investigate about creating a custom `Annotation` which serve as pointcut for a custom `Advice` which, in turn, will use ConfigurationProperties (the context) for selecting at runtime different bean methods. Something similar to the @Flip annotation used by [ff4j](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j) feature flag framework

Answer (score 0):

This implementation worked for me:

```java
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class HelloDelegate implements HelloService {

  @Delegate // lombok delegate (for the sake of brevity)
  private final HelloService delegate;

  public HelloDelegate(
    // just inject value from Spring configuration
    @Value("${country}") String country
  ) {
  HelloService impl = null;
  switch (country) {
    case "it":
      this.delegate = new HelloIT();
      break;
    default:
      this.delegate = new HelloUS();
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

It works the following way:

1. When first invocation of service method happens Spring creates bean `HelloDelegate` with configuration effective at that moment; bean is put into refresh scope cache
2. Because of `@RefreshScope` whenever configuration is changed (`country` property particularly in this case) `HelloDelegate` bean gets cleared from refresh scope cache
3. When next invocation happens, Spring has to create bean again because it does not exist in cache, so step 1 is repeated with new `country` property

As far as I watched the behavior of this implementation, Spring will try to avoid recreating `RefreshScope` bean if it's configuration was untouched.

---

I was looking for more generic solution of doing such "runtime" implementation replacement when found this question. This implementation has one significant disadvantage: if delegated beans have complex non-homogeneous configuration (e.g. each bean has it's own properties) code becomes lousy and therefore unsafe.

I use this approach to provide additional testability for artifacts. So that QA would be able to switch between stub and real integration without significant efforts. I would strongly recommend to **avoid using such approach for business** functionality.