# Enable and disable endpoints at runtime with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Let's say I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("v1/remain")
    public MyObject getRemain() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I enable or disable this endpoint at runtime dynamically with Spring boot? Also, is it possible to change this without having to restart the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To dynamically reload beans when a property changes, you could use Spring boot actuator + Spring cloud so that you have access to the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint.

This can be done by adding the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The latter does require that you add the BOM for Spring cloud, which is:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now you can enable the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint by setting the following property:

```
 management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
```

This will allow you to send a `POST` call to `/actuator/refresh`, which will return an array of all changed properties.

---

By using the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint, it also allows you to use the `@RefreshScope` annotation to recreate beans. However, there are a few limitations:

1. `@RefreshScope` recreates the bean without re-evaluating conditionals that might have changed due to the refresh. That means that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56415107) doesn't work with `@RefreshScope`, as seen in [the comment section of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008261/use-spring-refreshscope-conditional-annotations-to-replace-bean-injection-at).
2. `@RefreshScope` doesn't work nicely with filters either, as seen in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7151).

That means you have two options:

1. Add the `@RefreshScope` to the controller and **do the conditional logic by yourself**, for example:

   ```
   @RefreshScope
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/api/foo")
   public class FooController {
       @Value("${foo.controller.enabled}")
       private boolean enabled;

       @GetMapping
       public ResponseEntity<String> getFoo() {
           return enabled ? ResponseEntity.of("bar") : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
       }
   }
   ```

   This means you would have to add this condition to all endpoints within your controller. I haven't verified if you could use this with aspects.
2. Another solution is to **not use `@RefreshScope`** to begin with, and to lazily fetch the property you want to validate. This allows you to use it with a filter, for example:

   ```
   public class FooFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
       private Environment environment;

       public FooFilter(Environment environment) {
           this.environment = environment;
       }

       @Override
       protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
           if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(environment.getProperty("foo.controller.enabled"))) {
               filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
           } else {
               response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You'll have to register the filter as well, for example by using:

   ```
   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean<FooFilter> fooFilter(Environment environment) {
       FilterRegistrationBean<FooFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
       bean.setFilter(new FooFilter(environment));
       bean.addUrlPatterns("/api/foo");
       return bean;
   }
   ```

   Please note, this approach only fetches the property dynamically from the `Environment`. Refreshing the `Environment` itself still requires you to use the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint.

Comment: +1. If we don't want to get into the additional complexity of spring cloud. A JMX method can be an easy alternative.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Spring Boot Actuator also allows you to call endpoints using JMX if I'm not mistaken. However, enabling the refresh actuator endpoint relies on using the `spring-cloud-starter` (doesn't require any other Spring cloud stuff though). If you don't want to rely on Spring Cloud, you could write your own refresh endpoint. A good starting point is [this code from Spring Cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshEndpointAutoConfiguration.java).

Answer (score 13):

You can either use @ConditionalOnExpression or @ConditionalOnProperty

```
@RestController
@ConditionalOnExpression("${my.property:false}")
@RequestMapping(value = "my-end-point", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "endpoint1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> endpoint1(
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello world", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Now if you want the above controller to work, you need to add following in application.properties file.

```
my.controller.enabled=true
```

Without the above statement, it will behave like the above controller don't exist.

Similiarly,

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("my.property")
```

behaves exactly same as above; if the property is present and "true", the component works, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: When the program runs when it is true to false nothing happens

Comment: How do I change the configuration in runtime mode to apply to the program? (property dynamic)

Comment: How to "property dynamic"?

Comment: This is a static behavior not a dynamic one.

Comment: How can i use same functionality on controller's end-point?. Means i want to disable only end-point not whole controller.

Comment: This only works for the entire controller. This doesn't work for a single endpoint within the controller.

Comment: The swagger documentation is still showing the endpoints after this. Is it the expected behaviour ? Shouldn't  the endpoints be no more seen in the swagger-ui ?

Comment: Question is about runtime operation.